# Fresh install Laravel with Sail, How do you fix permission issue

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

Created a Laravel project using this command:

```
$ curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

My username on my machine is `tonysong`:

```
$ ls -al
total 376
drwxr-xr-x 13 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 24 11:17 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 24 16:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tonysong tonysong   1686 Agu 22 20:26 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   1814 Agu 22 20:26 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong 281237 Agu 24 11:17 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 database
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   2894 Agu 24 11:17 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong    258 Agu 22 20:26 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   1202 Agu 24 11:17 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   1075 Agu 24 11:17 .env.example
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong    179 Agu 22 20:26 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong    203 Agu 22 20:26 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  3 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 lang
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong    285 Agu 22 20:26 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   1105 Agu 24 11:17 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 public
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong   3977 Agu 22 20:26 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 routes
drwxr-xr-x  5 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 22 20:26 tests
drwxr-xr-x 40 tonysong tonysong   4096 Agu 24 11:17 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 tonysong tonysong    263 Agu 22 20:26 vite.config.js
```

but then I checked the permissions inside the docker:

```
$ sail shell
$ ls -al
total 376
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4096 Aug 24 04:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Aug 24 04:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    258 Aug 22 13:26 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1202 Aug 24 04:17 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1075 Aug 24 04:17 .env.example
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    179 Aug 22 13:26 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    203 Aug 22 13:26 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3977 Aug 22 13:26 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   1686 Aug 22 13:26 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1814 Aug 22 13:26 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 281237 Aug 24 04:17 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 database
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2894 Aug 24 04:17 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 lang
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    285 Aug 22 13:26 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1105 Aug 24 04:17 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 public
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 routes
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Aug 22 13:26 tests
drwxr-xr-x 40 root root   4096 Aug 24 04:17 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    263 Aug 22 13:26 vite.config.js
```

Some people suggested fixing this using `chown`:

```
$ sail root-shell
$ chown -R sail .
```

But this approach prevents me from doing write/delete/create any file from local (not from docker)

I've tried to rebuild the container:

```
$ sail build --no-cache
```

But no luck.

Additional information:

```
php -v
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:40:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

```
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

OS information

```
neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               tonysong@tonysong-desktop 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 1 day, 2 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 1861 (dpkg), 15 (snap) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 2560x1440 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: GNOME 42.2 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Adwaita 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Yaru-sage-dark [GTK2/3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Yaru-sage [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: gnome-terminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 3.600GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Memory: 12464MiB / 15919MiB 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                   
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Could anyone please help with this? thank you.

Comment: Did the `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` command give an error? It should already fix the permissions, or did you run the command as root with `sudo`?

Comment: Hi @JohnZwarthoed, no error, it's finished successfully, also, I don't that command run as root, you can see on the post above if I run "$ ls", the file names are under my name "tonysong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that using Docker Desktop is the cause.

***Solution:***

Uninstall Docker Desktop, **and use only Docker Engine.**